# Introduction part in Deep Learning with Keras using Python

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Instruction of questions:

1. Instantiate a Sequential model.
2. Add a Dense layer of 50 neurons with an input shape of 1 neuron.
3. Add two Dense layers of 50 neurons each and 'relu' activation.
4. End your model with a Dense layer with a single neuron and no activation.

Below is my code:

```
# Instantiate a Sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Add a Dense layer with 50 neurons and an input of 1 neuron
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'))

# Add two Dense layers with 50 neurons and relu activation
model.add(Dense(____,____=____))
model.____

# End your model with a Dense layer and no activation
model.____
```

I am confused about the part

```
model.add(Dense(____,____=____))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense), the only required parameter for the Dense layer is `units`, which is the number of neurons. The default activation function is `None`, so if you want it to be `"relu"`, do `activation="relu"`.

In conclusion, this is that piece of code that creates a Dense layer with 50 neurons and activation as `relu`:

```py
model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `model.add(Dense(___,___=___))`, you have three blanks. The first one is for mentioning number of neurons, the second one for saying that you want to set some value for `activation` and the third one is for setting that value as `relu`.

So you will get `model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))`

More information can be found in the [Dense layer documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense).